# how to stop the countdown loop

Tags: javascript, python, android

I am trying to create a countdown, how when it goes to 0 it will stop the loop and show a message

```
import time

countdown = 100

while True:

    display = " [ Countdown {:03d} ] ".format(countdown)

    print(display, end="\r")

    time.sleep(2)

    countdown -= 1
```

Comment: This post doesn't seem to be tagged correctly.

Comment: You have an endless loop with `while True`; change it to check some condition, like `while countdown > 0:`.

Comment: > Mous <: i know tagging, because stackoverflow doesn't let me tag too short, i have to add 1/2 random tag

Comment: > Robert <: Thanks for pointing me, this code works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `while` loop is only executed while the expression after the `while` is true. In this case, that expression is `True`, which always evaluates to `True`.

Consider replacing this with something like `countdown > 0` . Once this statement evaluates to `False`, the execution will exit the `while` loop and continue to code afterwards, where you can put your shown message.

Total code:

```
import time
countdown = 100
while countdown > 0: # While the condition is true, it will keep looping
    display = " [ Countdown {:03d} ] ".format(countdown)
    print(display, end="\r")
    time.sleep(2)
    countdown -= 1
print('Countdown finished!') # Executed only once the loop is finished
```

If this answer helped, click the green checkmark to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

Replace  the true value in the while loop that makes the condition for infinite loop
with

```
 import time

 countdown = 100

 while countdown >0:

   display = " [ Countdown {:03d} ] ".format(countdown)

   print(display, end="\r")

   time. Sleep(2)

   countdown -= 1
```

Comment: This code doesn't meet the question spec, specifically the "show a message" part. Additionally, `time.sleep` has been mistyped as `time.Sleep`, which will raise an `AttributeError`

Comment: the rest you do it, or you have to explicitly write your question here.